# Custom queries don't work with interface projections in Spring Data Neo4j repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

To exclude some of the entity's fields I created an interface projection which returns only some of the fields.

I wanted to add a method in the repository interface (which extends **Neo4jRepository**) which uses a custom query written in Cypher (using the **@Query** annotation)

This method works if I set the return object to Entity but it returns `null` when the return object is set to the projection. Projections work with the normal repository methods (without custom queries)

Example code:
*Also - I use lombok but I doubt that it makes any difference here*

*PersonEntity.java*

```
@NodeEntity
@Data
public class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  @Property("first_name")
  private String firstName;
  @Property("last_name")
  private String lastName;
  @Property("is_man")
  private boolean isMan;
```

*PersonProjection.java*

```
public interface PersonProjection {
  Long getId();
  String getFirstName();
  boolean getIsMan();
}
```

*PersonRepository.java*

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Person, Long> {
  @Query("MATCH (n:`Person`) WHERE n.`is_man` = true WITH n RETURN n")
  List<PersonProjection> findMen(); // doesn't work, returns null

  List<PersonProjection> findAllByIsManTrue(); // works, returns the list of men
}
```

Some things to note:

1. This cypher query is 100% correct. Tested it in Neo4j Desktop and it works as expected
2. Of course this example is trivial and I normally wouldn't need a custom query for that but the problem will get back to me when some more complex queries arise
3. As I said, the custom query method works when I use entity instead of projection. And while using projection, the debug log says `looking for concrete class to resolve label: Person` so maybe it somehow forces the usage of entity? Just a thing I thought about
4. I'm using the latest version of `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j`

Is there a way to fix it? How could I do it? And if the fix is not possible, what's the other way I could approach this issue?

Comment: Did you try annotating the PersonProjection with @QueryResult (org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.QueryResult)

Comment: I did. It returns JSON Object with proper fields but they are all `null`.
I also receive a warning, but I can't tell if it's relevant: `QueryResult interface method toString doesn't appear to be a getter and therefore may not return the correct result.`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need @QueryResult on your interface
2. The query you use will not work with SDN(spring data neo4j), it needs slight modification while returning the result as below
   @Query("MATCH (n:`Person`) WHERE n.`is_man` = true WITH n RETURN ID(n) as id,n.first_name as firstName, n.is_man as isMan")

Then it will work.  Below is the example that works fine

```
 @QueryResult
public interface PersonProjection {
    String getName();
}
  public interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Person, Long> {

   
    @Query("MATCH (pr:Person) return pr.name as name")
    public List<PersonProjection> getPersonWithAllFriends();

   

}
```